# How to make method don't call again after user returned to this fragment from another?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have one method(let's call it `getData`) in my fragment(let's call it `List`) which I call in `onCreateView`.
This method load some data from server and put it to some views.
In my fragment I have one button which open another fragment(Let's call it `Detail`), and when I go back to `List` `onCreateView` calling again and data start load again.

I tried to put `getData` into `onCreate`... and in fact it must works, and mustn't call `getData` again...

But `getData` works with views whick initialize only in onCreateView and another methods after `onCreateView` and all that methods always recalling when I return to `List` from `Detail`.

How do I make don't recall `getData` when I return to `List` from `Detail`.

I'm so sorry for my bad English and grammar mistakes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of All override onStop method by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
it will look like this

```
public class yourFragment extends Fragment{
boolean isReturned = false;




@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    isReturned = true;
}



public void getData(){
   if(!isReturned){
    //fetch data
     }
}
```

Comment: i think ive understand ur idea. and when i have to make isReturned true? in onpause or in onStop?

Comment: you can use in one of both methods

Comment: both methods fires up when fragment goes to background

Comment: ok. and onPause and onStop calls when curr fragment go away from the first position of stack, yes?

Comment: thank u very much. i pressed green button cause i can do only this action. can't press up button cause i have low ratio. thank u